# Why git apply fails when /usr/bin/patch succeeds?

Tags: git, diff, patch

I've very often occurring this situation: I have a patch generated with `git format-patch` and I'm applying it with `git apply`and it fails with the message "Patch does not apply".

Then I, surprised, try to apply it with `patch -p1 -i …`, and it succeeds, without any problems, with just a few hunk offsets (but as large as e.g.: 300 lines).

I wonder why it is so? I've used `--recount` option with `apply`, so it should be also accepting hunk offsets. I've even used `-3` for three way merge, which helps in 50% of cases.

I would also like to note how **simple** this patch is (attached) – here is its summary:

```
 lib/keybind.c          |  1 +
 lib/keybind.h          |  1 +
 misc/mc.default.keymap |  1 +
 misc/mc.emacs.keymap   |  1 +
 src/editor/edit-impl.h |  1 +
 src/editor/edit.c      | 21 +++++++++++++++++++++
 src/keybind-defaults.c |  1 +
```

I'm applying it versus current HEAD of [neo-mc](https://github.com/neo-mc/neo-mc). The patch is already merged there, however first I'm applying reversed patch (no surprise: with `patch`), and then try to apply it from the file (attached below).

So **WHY** doesn't `git apply` correctly handle this simple patch? Couldn't git programers code or at least copy a decent tool (i.e.: `patch`)? Or am I'm missing something?

I've also occurred a similar important issue: a patch generated with `format-patch` wasn't applying even with `patch`, so I've did `git diff  master..BRANCH > adhoc.patch` and **it worked** !! I was able to apply the patch with `/usr/bin/patch`, I didn't even look behind at the `format-patch`/`apply` combo.

Here is output from `git apply -3 --recount patches/CenterView_v3.patch`:

```
error: patch failed: src/editor/edit-impl.h:233
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to 'src/editor/edit-impl.h' cleanly.
error: patch failed: src/editor/edit.c:3766
error: repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge.
error: src/editor/edit.c: patch does not apply
```

And here from `patch -p1 -i …`:

```
patching file lib/keybind.c
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 69 (offset 5 lines).
patching file lib/keybind.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 57 (offset 2 lines).
patching file misc/mc.default.keymap
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 278 (offset 3 lines).
patching file misc/mc.emacs.keymap
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 277 (offset 2 lines).
patching file src/editor/edit-impl.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 280 with fuzz 1 (offset 47 lines).
patching file src/editor/edit.c
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 3281 (offset 258 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 4085 with fuzz 1 (offset 319 lines).
patching file src/keybind-defaults.c
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 431 (offset 11 lines).
```

Patch contents:

```
From b7f010902585692326161e6e4b16fcd9a9378854 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Sebastian Gniazdowski <sgniazdowski@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 23 Jan 2021 23:16:37 -0600
Subject: CenterView action

---
 lib/keybind.c          |  1 +
 lib/keybind.h          |  1 +
 misc/mc.default.keymap |  1 +
 misc/mc.emacs.keymap   |  1 +
 src/editor/edit-impl.h |  1 +
 src/editor/edit.c      | 21 +++++++++++++++++++++
 src/keybind-defaults.c |  1 +
 7 files changed, 27 insertions(+)

diff --git a/lib/keybind.c b/lib/keybind.c
index abd44d3e2..9ab8dd5a6 100644
--- a/lib/keybind.c
+++ b/lib/keybind.c
@@ -64,6 +64,7 @@ static name_keymap_t command_names[] = {
     ADD_KEYMAP_NAME (PageDown),
     ADD_KEYMAP_NAME (HalfPageUp),
     ADD_KEYMAP_NAME (HalfPageDown),
+    ADD_KEYMAP_NAME (CenterView),
     ADD_KEYMAP_NAME (Top),
     ADD_KEYMAP_NAME (Bottom),
     ADD_KEYMAP_NAME (TopOnScreen),
diff --git a/lib/keybind.h b/lib/keybind.h
index af019df09..1cef8138d 100644
--- a/lib/keybind.h
+++ b/lib/keybind.h
@@ -55,6 +55,7 @@ enum
     CK_PageDown,
     CK_HalfPageUp,
     CK_HalfPageDown,
+    CK_CenterView,
     CK_Top,
     CK_Bottom,
     CK_TopOnScreen,
diff --git a/misc/mc.default.keymap b/misc/mc.default.keymap
index 2931ddd0a..fe9b5adb1 100644
--- a/misc/mc.default.keymap
+++ b/misc/mc.default.keymap
@@ -275,6 +275,7 @@ End = end
 Tab = tab; shift-tab; ctrl-tab; ctrl-shift-tab
 Undo = ctrl-u
 Redo = alt-r
+CenterView = alt-c
 Top = ctrl-home; alt-lt
 Bottom = ctrl-end; alt-gt
 ScrollUp = ctrl-up
diff --git a/misc/mc.emacs.keymap b/misc/mc.emacs.keymap
index 7cc305db7..9d8ee0fd8 100644
--- a/misc/mc.emacs.keymap
+++ b/misc/mc.emacs.keymap
@@ -275,6 +275,7 @@ End = end; ctrl-e
 Tab = tab; shift-tab; ctrl-tab; ctrl-shift-tab
 Undo = ctrl-u
 # Redo =
+CenterView = alt-c
 Top = ctrl-home; alt-lt
 Bottom = ctrl-end; alt-gt
 ScrollUp = ctrl-up
diff --git a/src/editor/edit-impl.h b/src/editor/edit-impl.h
index 3ad04dbea..69f8c1683 100644
--- a/src/editor/edit-impl.h
+++ b/src/editor/edit-impl.h
@@ -233,6 +233,7 @@ void edit_save_size (WEdit * edit);
 gboolean edit_handle_move_resize (WEdit * edit, long command);
 void edit_toggle_fullscreen (WEdit * edit);
 void edit_move_to_line (WEdit * e, long line);
+void edit_center_display (WEdit * e, long diff);
 void edit_move_display (WEdit * e, long line);
 void edit_word_wrap (WEdit * edit);
 int edit_sort_cmd (WEdit * edit);
diff --git a/src/editor/edit.c b/src/editor/edit.c
index 50879cee2..9146069a2 100644
--- a/src/editor/edit.c
+++ b/src/editor/edit.c
@@ -3023,6 +3023,22 @@ edit_move_to_line (WEdit * e, long line)
     edit_scroll_screen_over_cursor (e);
 }
 
+/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
+/** scroll window so that current line is in center; the diff is a relative offset from that
+  * position */
+
+void
+edit_center_display (WEdit * e, long diff)
+{
+    int center_line_diff = WIDGET (e)->lines / 2 + diff;
+    int current_line = e->curs_row;
+
+    if (current_line < center_line_diff)
+        edit_scroll_upward (e, center_line_diff - current_line);
+    else
+        edit_scroll_downward (e, current_line - center_line_diff);
+}
+
 /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
 /** scroll window so that first visible line is 'line' */
 
@@ -3766,6 +3782,11 @@ edit_execute_cmd (WEdit * edit, long command, int char_for_insertion)
         }
         break;
 
+    case CK_CenterView:
+        /* Center view at cursor line. */
+        edit_center_display (edit, 0);
+        break;
+
     case CK_Top:
     case CK_MarkToFileBegin:
         edit_move_to_top (edit);
diff --git a/src/keybind-defaults.c b/src/keybind-defaults.c
index 7b87c2f5a..ad4b59780 100644
--- a/src/keybind-defaults.c
+++ b/src/keybind-defaults.c
@@ -420,6 +420,7 @@ static const global_keymap_ini_t default_editor_keymap[] = {
     {"Goto", "alt-l; alt-shift-l"},
     {"Refresh", "ctrl-l"},
     {"Shell", "ctrl-o"},
+    {"CenterView", "alt-c"},
     {"Top", "ctrl-home; ctrl-pgup; alt-lt"},
     {"Bottom", "ctrl-end; ctrl-pgdn; alt-gt"},
     {"TopOnScreen", "ctrl-pgup"},
-- 
2.28.0
```

Answer (score 1):

(One executive-summary TL;DR: patches are not commits; format-patch is meant for commits.  The old `patch` command is about patches, and `git apply` is something between a transition tool and just part of `git am`.)

There are a couple of key issues here:

- From your `patch` output, it appears that some parts of the patch are already applied and some are not.  The `patch` command will ask about using the reversal option for each hunk, but `git apply` requires that the reversal apply to *every* hunk, or *no* hunk.  So it won't do what patch does here.
- Given that some patches therefore won't apply, `git apply` *requires* the `--reject` option to apply the remaining patches.  The `patch` command assumes the equivalent (is always willing to create a `.rej` file).  (In your case, letting patch un-apply half the diffs and apply the other half takes care of this instead.)
- `patch` assumes a default fuzz factor of 2; several of your patches apply with fuzz.  The fuzz factor is the number of context lines that `patch` is allowed to *ignore*.  By default, `git apply` requires that *all* context lines match: this is the equivalent of `-F 0` in `patch`.  You can get the effect of a fuzz factor in `git patch` using the `-C` argument.

So, if you ran `git apply -C 1 --reject`, this patch would likely be applied with rejections.  The result would not match the result you get from `patch` unless you say no to each reversal.

(Side note: `--recount` is really for *edited* patches, not for context search adjustments.)

#### On format-patch

> I've also occurred a similar important issue: a patch generated with `format-patch` wasn't applying even with `patch`, so I've did `git diff master..BRANCH > adhoc.patch` and it worked !!

This is both unsurprising (in that it happens), and deserving of closer attention (when it does happen) since it means you are not getting what you are hoping to get.  Look closer, so as to see what *is*, and use that to decide how to get what you want—whatever that may be in the end.

What `git format-patch` does is to turn some *ordinary commit*—i.e., some single-parent commit—or some series of such commits, into email-ready text files containing enough information to reconstruct each commit.<sup>1</sup>  (The `git am` command does the reconstruction.  Reconstructing these commits later, e.g., from a mailbox format input file, will generally retain the original author, but produce a different committer.)

What `git diff` does is take *any two arbitrary commits*<sup>2</sup> and *compare them* and produce a patch that, if applied, turns the snapshot given by the left-side commit into the snapshot given by the right-side commit.  Here, the two commits are those at the tip of `master`, and those at the tip of `BRANCH`.  The two-dot syntax, `git diff master..BRANCH`, is slowly being deprecated in favor of the `git diff master BRANCH` syntax, but both mean exactly the same thing.

Note that there may be *no* set of commits that would be emitted by a single `git format-patch` command that would transform the tip-of-`master` snapshot into the tip-of-`BRANCH` snapshot.  For instance, suppose we had the following commits:

```
          I--J--K   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          L--M--N   <-- BRANCH
```

The `git format-patch` command can format the `L-M-N` patches in one go (producing three email-able reconstruction files), but these need to be applied to commit `H` to reproduce new commits that match `L`, `M`, and `N`.  Or, `git format-patch` can format the `I-J-K` patches in one go; but these would also need to be applied to commit `H`, not commit `K`, so as to produce commit `K`.

If what you *have* is a snapshot (not a Git repository, just a snapshot) that matches commit `K`, you could take the three patches that convert `H` to `K` and *reverse* them to get three more snapshots locally that are equivalent to `J`, `I`, and then `H`; you could then add, in the normal forwards direction, the three patches that produce `L`, `M`, and finally `N`.

But, as we can see from the graph above, there is no *commit* that takes us, in one step, from commit `K` to commit `N`.  To get a *patch* that takes us there in one step, we *must* diff commits `K` and `N` directly.  Such a patch cannot recreate any of the preceding commits: if all we have is the snapshot that goes with `K`, and we apply this patch, we get the snapshot that goes with `N`, but we have no idea what `H` looks like, for instance.

If the recipient of some patch (or some format-patch output) has the appropriate Git repository, they can apply format-patch output as long as they have the required base commit(s), and get equivalent commits (albeit with different committer information).  This can be particularly helpful for close review, for instance.  But if the recipient does not have the requisite commits—perhaps not even a Git repository at all—the `format-patch` results are not so helpful, and a plain one-off `git diff` patch may be best anyway.  The details vary depending on the recipient.

---

<sup>1</sup>The format-patch command can also produce a single stream of output (`--stdout`) suitable for feeding directly to `git am`, but these days it's more useful for producing a directory full of email-able files, suitable for feeding to `git send-email`.  This works well with the emailed patch methods used by various Linux groups, the Git project itself, and so on.

<sup>2</sup>The `git diff` command can take other inputs that are not necessarily commits, but in this case (`master..BRANCH`), we're getting the mode that compares two commits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see what you meant with the second subquestion – and let's focus on 1st, as it's fully reproducible. You've missed one paragraph from the 1st question – the one stating that I have been first **reversing the patch** to then re-apply it with `git apply`. So, the `patch`'s output is the (accident) log from this reversal, instead of the output of the re-apply. However, if `patch` is being able to *reverse* a patch, then for sure it's also capable that it's capable of applying it. So basically, `git apply` fails to reapply patch that have been just reversed by `patch`…

Comment: Ah. After "un-patching" with a reverse patch with `patch`, you're still left with the fact that this patch doesn't apply as is because the *contexts* don't match. The `patch` program allowed for that with fuzz but `git apply` doesn't: you need `-C`. It also looks like two of the patches *weren't* reversed, so I think you would still need `--reject` as well.

Comment: Thanks, the patch applied with `-C 1`. I wonder if this is the same as with patch's fuzz? Doesn't fuzz mean that the context still matches but fuzz lines earlier/later, while `-C 1` ignores most of it?

Comment: The `-C` option makes `git patch` completely ignore some context lines, which is not as fancy as patch's fuzz option. The fuzz option to patch sets the number of context lines that patch will (a) throw out but then (b) report having thrown out, so you get to see how many that was. If the actual number of context lines is 3 and patch says "with fuzz 2", patch threw out 2 of the 3, so `-C 1` will work; if it's, say, 10 context lines and patch says "fuzz 7" you'd want `-C 3`, and so on.

Comment: Hence `-C 1` is going as low as patch *might*. Possibly overkill and might overmatch, almost as if you were applying a non-context patch (but not *quite* that bad).

Comment: Then I'll stay with `patch`. Too bad that git hackers didn't replicate `patch` features. I've already switched to `patch` even for stash applying, by providing a `tig` binding.